# Using odometry from hector_mapping for move_base (Nav stack)

Tags: navigation, odometry, mapping, move-base, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

To run move_base (part of the Navigation stack), I need to provide an odom topic which move_base can subscribe to.

I use hector_mapping for odometry on my robot, and have set the `pub_map_odom_transform` option of my hector_mapping node to true to publish *a tf* between the map & the odom frames.

**Is it possible to output odom as a topic from hector_mapping?** If not, how should I go about constructing odom messages from hector_mapping topics? (I have a hunch that this is possible seeing as a tf from map to odom is available..)

Thank you in advance,

Ernest

**Edit**: Alternatively, is there a way in move_base to use the incoming map->odom tf for odometry (as opposed to the odom topic) ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62081/using-odometry-from-hector_mapping-for-move_base-(nav-stack)/) by [Ernest](https://answers.ros.org/users/4002/ernest/) on ROS Answers with karma: 341 on 2013-05-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually I've figured it out.

It turns out that move_base doesn't need the odom topic, it can get odometry information from the tf that is being published by hector_mapping!

---

Originally posted by [Ernest](https://answers.ros.org/users/4002/ernest/) with karma: 341 on 2013-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [simk0024](https://answers.ros.org/users/37383/simk0024/) on 2021-06-09**:
Hi @Ernest, i wonder how did you configure the launch file to get odom tf out from hector_mapping and use it for move_base.